# Finite state machine that accepts every word with at least one c, or different value of parity of the counts of a's and c's

Tags: automata, finite-automata

few weeks ago I had an exam in automata theory course and I've been asked to write the following non-deterministic finite automata

> Write a NFA which accepts the following language - the language contains all the words (above `{a, b, c}`) with at least 1 appearance of the letter c, **or** the parity of the count of the letter a is different from the parity of the letter c.

and I answered with the following state machine:

[image: the finite state machine I answered with]

which was totally incorrect, and I'm trying to understand why. I do know there's a possibility to solve that question with 2 states machine, but I'd like to stick with the current solution.
I do understand that the arrow from q2 to itself should contain c also, but does it makes the machine completely inaccurate? how would you rank that kind of solution from 1 to 20?

Comment: Are you aware that this machine is non-deterministic ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust it can be non-deterministic. I think the requirements allow string with no c (and recognizing its parity with 0 as even)

Comment: @YvesDaoust that's why I bolded the "or".

Comment: Ooooops, sorry, I read **and**.

Comment: *"I do know there's a possibility to solve that question with 2 states machine"* - what makes you think so? It seems to me that at least three states must be necessary. There are partial inputs like `aba` where the string is not accepted but will be if another `a` is received; other inputs like `ab` where the string is accepted but will not be if another `a` is received, and inputs like `bc` where whatever comes next, the string will always be accepted. So the strings `aba`, `ab` and `bc` must leave the automaton in distinct states. But three states is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that the language can alternatively defined as the set of strings where the count of $a$ is odd or there is at least one $c$. If we have any $c$ in the string, the parity of $a$ doesn't matter – hence the parity of $a$ matters only when there are no $c$ in the string so the parity of $c$ is even. You can construct a three-state automaton fairly close to your current one:

- $q_0$ is the initial state: even number of $a$ and no $c$ has been read. Non-accepting.
- $q_1$ is the state where an odd number of $a$ has been read, but no $c$. Accepting.
- $q_2$ is the state where a $c$ has been read. Accepting.

Since all strings containing any $c$ must be accepted, reading $c$ from any state should result in $q_2$. We are going to accept the string anyway, so we can stop tracking the $a$ parity, and any symbol in $q_2$ loops back to $q_2$. Apart from that, tracking the parity of $a$ is done like you do it between $q_0$ and $q_1$.

I don't believe a two-state DFA or even NFA exists for this language, as it must have at least two accepting states: one that cannot be exited (for strings that contain any $c$) and one that can be exited (for strings that contain an odd number of $a$, no $c$). However, there are clearly non-accepted strings too, so a non-accepted state is also needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the second clause with two states with meanings "same parity" vs. "different parities", both $a$ and $c$ switching between both.

But I don't see how to avoid two additional states ("odd $a$, no $c$" and "even $a$, no $c$") to handle the "at least one $c$" clause.